# Redirect root HTTP to root HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, apache2

I want that if someone visits http://domain.com that he is redirected to https://domain.com

The `.htaccess` file is located at `/var/www/html` with the following content

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>
```

My `apache2.conf` contains:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
```

But it does not work, displaying:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

**Edit:** I removed the SSLRequireSSL line and disabled the cache in Firefox that saves redirections. If I visit http://domain.com it redirects me to https://domain.com. But still it does not do it for subdirectories as well. If I visit http://domain.com/sub I want to be redirected to https://domain.com

Comment: Define "does not work". Nothing happens? Something unexpected happens? ...?

Comment: commenting out the mentioned lines does not work either :(

Comment: Does `https://domain.com/` URL work directly in browser?

Comment: @anubhava yes it, does! i am using a virtual machine running ubuntu server and i access the website via the local ip address

Comment: SSL certs may not go well with IP address in URL. Do you get same content while using `https://domain.com/` and `http://domain.com/`?

Comment: i set SSL to be required so i cannot open http://domain.com

Comment: Do you have a 443 vhost setup? You're not showing your entire apache2.conf file.

Comment: ok, i disalbed SSLRequireSSL and i switched off the redirection cache.. my bad. still i want to be able to redirect every request to the same url but with https. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subdirectory I was talking about was a special one... Didn't think that it would matter. It is an owncloud installation which is shipped with an own .htaccess. My .htaccess was overwritten by that one which did not include my rewrite rule.

My second mistake was, like already mentioned that I had the `SSLRequireSSL` property set. If this is activated it seems that any .htaccess is just ignored.

I also removed the enclosing if statments from the .htaccess like anubhava suggested.